# Problema com o a função random python

Tags: python-3.x

Ola estou com um problema de typeErro. mas não sei oq pode ser, sou iniciante em python

```py
import random 
def ataque(bonus, defesa, dano, bonus_dano):
    dano_total = [(random.randint(1, dano)+bonus_dano) for i in range(1)]
    ataque_total = [(random.randint(1, 20)) for i in range(1)]
    dano_critico = [(random.randint(1, dano)+2*bonus_dano) for i in range(2)]
    total_dano_critico=sum(dano_critico)

    if ataque_total == 20 and ataque_total + bonus_dano >= defesa:
        print(total_dano_critico)
    else:
        if ataque_total+bonus_dano >= defesa :
          print(dano_total)
        else:
          print("errou")
```

Comment: E qual é **exatamente** a mensagem do erro? Considerando que `bonus_dano` seja numérico, em `ataque_total + bonus_dano` você estaria somando uma lista com um número; qual seria o resultado esperado disso? Aliás, por que `dano_total`, `ataque_total` e `dano_critico` são listas?

Comment: da erro no if ataque_total+bonus_dano >= defesa :, então coloquei elas como listas pq no comando sum ela não faz o somatório se não for lista, ai eu tinha que escrever muito mais código e também foi para ter um código mais limpo.

Comment: vou tirar a lista desses que não tem necessidade. fazer uns testes, para ver se continua o problema. Eu posso somar um numero a todos os componentes de uma lista ?

Comment: obrigado pela atenção.